# Exporting function to TLD

Tags: jsp, taglib

I want to export this function to my `custom-functions.tld` file:

```
package com.site.vo;

public class Utils {
    public static String concat(String... values) {
        String out = "";

        for (String value : values) {
            out.concat(value);
        }

        return out;
    }
}
```

Here's my `custom-functions-tld` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.0">
<tlib-version>2.0</tlib-version>
<uri>/WEB-INF/custom-functions.tld</uri>
 <function>
  <description>Concatenate strings</description>
  <name>concat</name>
  <function-class>com.site.vo.Utils</function-class>
  <function-signature>java.lang.String concat(java.lang.String...)</function-signature>
 </function>
</taglib>
```

That `function-signature` didn't worked, I got the follow exception:

`org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The class java.lang.String... specified in the method signature in TLD for the function f:concat cannot be found. java.lang.String...`

Tried `java.lang.String[]`, but that one expects only one parameter (a list, d'oh!). I'm looking for the correct function-signature to export functions with multiple parameters.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6):

You should try to move to Java EE 6. You can use the new [Unified Expression Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Expression_Language) then and save yourself from the nightmare of creating your own taglib.

It allows you to directly call methods on your defined beans.